# Как сортировать объекты по первой букве свойств?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Приходит объект, в котором есть свойства. Как можно отсортировать объект в алфавитном порядке по первой букве свойств? Возможно ли это реализовать на jQuery ?

Пример объекта:

```
obj = {
  {
    name: "banan"
  }, {
    name: "ananas"
  }, {
    name: "grusha"
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, имели в виду массив `obj = [ ... ]`?

Comment: @ kmv, да массив

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/task/sort-objects вот почти ваша задача, нужно только изменить механику сортировки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с lodash

```js
var obj = [{
  name: "banan"
}, {
  name: "ananas"
}, {
  name: "grusha"
}]

var result = _.sortBy(obj, function(o) {
  return o.name.charAt(0);
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.name[0] < b.name[0]) return -1;
    if(a.name[0] > b.name[0]) return 1;
    return 0;
})
```

Comment: достаточно obj.sort(function(a, b) {  return a.name[0] > b.name[0]  })

Answer (score -3):

Вариант с AngularJS

```
<span ng-repeat="list in YourControllerAlias.obj | orderBy: 'name'">list.name</span>
```